# Lilypond – ties across staves

Tags: notation, lilypond, engraving

Is there a way in Lilypond to tie notes across two staves?
I have this fragment of an organ piece:

```
\version "2.18.2"
\language "deutsch"

global = {
  \key c \major
  \numericTimeSignature
  \time 3/4
  \set Timing.beamExceptions = #'()
}

right = \relative c'' {
  \global
  <h dis>2 (<cis e>4~<cis e>~<e, cis'>2~<cis e cis'>)r4
}

left = \relative c' {
  \global
  dis2 (e4~e cis2) gis'8(fis e dis e fis)
}
```

[image: fragment]

And I need to add the red tie between the two notes. (It is an organ piece and I need to let the organist know, that he is supposed to silently exchange fingers on the note and not to hit the tone twice.)

Comment: One solution may involve writing the `cis` in the lower voice and moving it to the upper staff. See also https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/71562/how-to-cross-staff-slurs-in-lilypond

Comment: I don't have Lilypond (so apologies if this doesn't work), but in my programme you can easily place a 'slur' between two staves, which would mimic a tie visually, but not audibly. See if that does the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do *not* pretend that this is an optimal answer, nor even a desired one. But here is one possible solution. Notice that I've moved some things around into multiple voices in a few spots. You can tweak the tie as you desire.

```
\version "2.18.2"
\language "deutsch"

global = {
  \key c \major
  \numericTimeSignature
  \time 3/4
  \set Timing.beamExceptions = #'()
}

right = \relative c'' {
  \global
  <h dis>2 (<cis e>4~ |
  <cis e>~ <e,^~ cis'~>2 |
  <e cis'>) r4
}

left = \relative c' {
  \global
  <<
    {
      \slurNeutral
      dis2 (e4~ |
      e \shape #'((0.5 . -10) (3 . -9) (1 . -5) (0 . -3)) Tie
        cis2)~ |
      \change Staff = "right"
      cis?
    }
    \\
    {
      s2. |
      s |
      \stemNeutral
      gis'8(fis e dis e fis)
    }
  >>
}

\score {
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = "right" \right
    \new Staff = "left" { \clef treble \left }
  >>
  \layout { }
}
```

[image]